Identify A Movie About A Home Invasion
I need help identifying a movie about a home invasion. I believe it was released around 2008-2010. The main bad guy was bald, and I recognized the actor. I think he was alone? I believe the house owners were a husband and wife. I remember loving it, and reading lots of positive reviews. I also think it had 2 different release names.
Ruled out:
-Cash
-The Strangers

Do you remember any plot-point or anything else.

Unfortunately not. I know it's not much to go on.

You have a list of films featuring home invasion here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_featuring_home_invasions

Was it released in the cinema?  Can you remember any scenes?  Any lines of dialog that might help?  Character's accents?  Was it set in the US?  I assume it was in English?

I looked through the list but no luck. The movie was in English, but I'm not sure what country it was set in.

Not exactly a home invasion, "House of Sand and Fog" is about a bald guy (Ben Kingsley) who buys a house that belongs to a woman (Jeniffer Connelly) and she refuses to give up the house. It is a drama and it was released in 2003.

Not "House Of Sand And Fog", but that one looks good.

Panic Room (2002)?

Not Panic Room. Jodi Foster is great in that though.

I found it! My description was a bit off. Yes it is a home invasion, but there's more to it than that. Also I had it backwards a man doesn't break into a couples' house they break into his. I can't wait to re-watch it.
Perfect Hideout (2008)
A couple fleeing the police need to find a place to lie low, but when they break into a house and take the owner hostage they find more than they bargained for.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1082064/

I believe you are talking about the Home Alone movie series. Boy is in a home, it gets invaded by two dimwits, one being bald. The houses the invade are typically owned by a wife and husband (they aren't there, only the boy is). I would give it a positive review.
It matches all your criteria except for maybe the release date, but you aren't sure of it. Hope this helps.

I think it's a stretch to match Home Alone to the OP's criteria. The year doesn't match, Joe Pesci in Home Alone isn't bald and the OP never mentions a child (which would be hard to forget from Home Alone).

Ah, okay. Sorry Andrew. I thought it was a good match.

We never know. Only the OP can decide.

Thanks for the suggestion, but it wasn't Home Alone. This was not family friendly film as it was violent.

Possibly "Lakeview Terrace"?
In it, an interracial couple moves into a home next to a single black detective, played by a bald Samuel L. Jackson, in which he enters their home and rigs several surprises and other tricks to try to force them to move out of the neighborhood.

Good guess, but it's not that. Great movie though.
